How to change Label in Tkinter dynamically
I am trying to write a timer and it should change the Label dynamically, and show time, but the label changes only when the counter function finishes work, somebody know how I can do this, or do I have only one way - async
This is my code(please don't laugh) and if you know how to solve this problem by async way please let me know
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time


def counter(timer_sum):
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(timer_sum)
    end_time = time.time()
---------------
# here 
def change(hours,minutes,seconds):
    time_counter_label.config(text=f'{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}')
--------------
def timer_function_start():

    count_time = input_timer.get()
    hours_box = int(spin_box_time_hours.get()) * 3600
    minute_box = int(spin_box_time_minuts.get()) * 60
    second_box = int(spin_box_time_second.get())
    timer_sum = hours_box + minute_box + second_box

    time_counter_label.config(text=f'{spin_box_time_hours.get()}:{spin_box_time_minuts.get()}:{spin_box_time_second.get()}')

    for item in range(timer_sum,0,-1):
        hours = int(item /3600) % 60
        minutes = int(item / 60) % 60
        seconds = item % 60
        print(f'{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}')
        change(hours,minutes,seconds)
        time.sleep(1)


    split_count = count_time.split(':')


    # counter(timer_sum)

    print("finish")


mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.minsize(300, 620)
timerImage = Image.open('img/timer.png')
timerImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(timerImage)

label_name = tkinter.Label(text='Timer')
label_name.pack()
label_name.config(height=3, width=4, font=("Arial", 24))

image_label = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, image=timerImage)
image_label.config(height=220, width=200)
image_label.pack()

button_timer_start = tkinter.Button(text='Start', command=timer_function_start)
button_timer_start.config(width=4, height=2)
button_timer_start.pack(pady=8)

button_timer_stop = tkinter.Button(text='Stop')
button_timer_stop.config(width=4, height=2)
button_timer_stop.pack()

time_counter_label = tkinter.Label(text='00:00:00')
time_counter_label.config(font=('Arial', 22))
time_counter_label.pack(pady=10)

timer_label = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, text="Enter Time")
timer_label.config(height=3, width=7)
timer_label.pack()

input_timer = tkinter.Entry()
input_timer.pack()

list_time_hours = list(map(lambda x: x, range(0, 24 + 1)))
list_time_minit = list(map(lambda x: x, range(0, 60 + 1)))
list_time_second = list(map(lambda x: x, range(0, 60 + 1)))

spin_box_time_hours = tkinter.Spinbox(mainWindow, values=list_time_hours)
spin_box_time_hours.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=20)
spin_box_time_hours.config(width=3)
spin_box_time_minuts = tkinter.Spinbox(mainWindow, values=list_time_minit)
spin_box_time_minuts.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=20)
spin_box_time_minuts.config(width=3)
spin_box_time_second = tkinter.Spinbox(mainWindow, values=list_time_second)
spin_box_time_second.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx=20)
spin_box_time_second.config(width=3)

mainWindow.mainloop()



What do I enter in Entry widget do?

If you're working on a tkinter app and need to update the UI periodically, don't use time.sleep(). It blocks the main thread, which prevents the UI from updating until the sleep is over. Instead, use the after() method in tkinter. This schedules a function to be called after a specified amount of time without blocking the main thread.
To make it work, modify your timer_function_start function like this:
def timer_function_start():
   # ... your existing setup code for timer_sum ...
   countdown(timer_sum)

def countdown(time_left):
   if time_left > 0:
      hours = int(time_left / 3600) % 60
      minutes = int(time_left / 60) % 60
      seconds = time_left % 60
      time_counter_label.config(text=f'{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}')
      # Schedule the countdown function to be called after 1000ms (1 second)
      mainWindow.after(1000, countdown, time_left - 1)
   else:
      print("finish")

